# Water solubility comparison of stereoisomers of bicyclo [4.4.0] decane-3,4-diol

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, alcohols, hydrogen-bond

[image]

I think, (I) must be more soluble in water. It is due to trans configuration and thus, forming more effectively inter-molecular hydrogen bonds with water molecules.